# Why can't char works but int does

Tags: c, char, int

```
char array[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,6,7};
printf("%c\n", array[5]);
```

This returns "  ". Nothing but when I change the char to int it prints "5". I tot char can accept numbers from -128 to 127?

```
int array[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,6,7};
printf("%i\n", array[5]);
```

Answer (score 4):

When you print the `char`, C assumes the value stored is supposed to represent [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) encoded text. Accessing `array[5]` yields the value `6`, which corresponds the ASCII value `ACK`. This character is not printable, which is why you see no output.

The *character* `6` is represented by the ASCII value `54`. To produce this value, use the `char` literal `'6'`.

For example, try initializing your array as:

```
char array[]= {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','1','2','3','6','7'};
```

This will result in the behavior you expect.

Alternatively, you can print the character as a formatted integer by using the flag `%i` in place of `%c` in your first snippet.